# Rails View : Idiomatic way to show description for an association object that can be null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, idioms

Model `Member` belongs_to `Discipline`, i.e. user can have a discipline but it is optional.

I'm wondering what would be the idiomatic Rails way to show member's discipline when I show the user details.

My first approach

```
<b>Discipline:</b>
<%=h @member.discipline.name %>
```

works otherwise fine but fails with `NoMethodError` if member's discipline is `Nil`. In that case, I'd like to have nothing there.

A couple of alternatives I have are

- Define method `Member:discipline_name` that returns "" if member doesn't have a discipline
- Restrict output with if;

The alternative with "if" would be something like:

```
<b>Discipline:</b>
<% if @member.discipline %>
<%=h @member.discipline.name %>
<% end %>
```

This isn't a big decision to make but I'd like to know if there's an "idiomatic way" to do this or some helper/something or something else to consider.

br, Touko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, developing Wukerplank's answer further, following seems to work fine and be pretty concise:

```
<b>Discipline:</b>
<%=h @member.discipline.name if @member.discipline %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the idiomatic way would be:

```
<b>Discipline:</b>
<%=h @member.discipline.name if @member.displince.present? %>
```

Comment: My Rails doesn't seem to have _present?_ method neither for nil or my Model objects? But, tuning your anser by replacing the if condition with @member.discipline if pretty concise.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to display anything in case of non-existence, you can use the ternery operator:

```
<%= condition ? statement true : statement false %>

<%= @member.discipline ? @member.discipline.name : 'none' %>
```